# Update nested object in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update nested object in google's Firebase Cloud Firestore.
My database structure is:
collection 'users' 
-- documents (userId)
---- collection 'matrix
------ document 'service' (got more documents: same type different names)
 
-------- success: Story[]
-------- failure: Story[]
-------- name: string

Story Model:
 
`title: string
text: string
storyType: string ('success' | 'failure)
case: string (for instance 'service')
...`

now I'm using Angular and I want to update a single story using. How do I do that?
I know how to get the reference to the 'service' document

```
update(story: Story, userId:string){ }
```

`db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('matrix).doc(story.case).update()`
Do i need to update the whole document or can I reach the specific story by the story object (I know his type for instance 'success' and title is uniq) so I can search which has this title and update only this story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrayUnion and arrayRemove operators to add and remove elements from the array.

for example, to add a Story

```
  db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('matrix).doc(story.case).update(
    {"success": FieldValue.arrayUnion(someStory)}
    )
```

these operators treat array like sets. you can not access individual item by index.

official documentation here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: This worked for add/ delete but if I change only the property 'text' of the desired story it will add new story instead of updating the old one. 
I can remove the old and add the new edited story but I don't know if thats a good idea

Comment: I think there's no update function from firebase API for this situation.